# Macro to save as a new excel workbook in the same folder on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to create a new worksheet with the name 'WEDNESDAY.xls' in the same folder that the original is saved, regardless of whether I have copied this file to another location or not.

So far I have managed to create the file in the same folder, but when I copy the original to a new folder location, the code seems to fail.

So far I have the following:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
    "WEDNESDAY.xls" _
    , FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Always provide the full path when saving - you can use `ActiveWorkbook.Path` to get the folder location (note that doesn't come with a terminating separator so don't forget to add it when joining it with the file name)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  To clarify @TimWilliams response: ActiveWorkook.SaveAs FileName := ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\WEDNESDAY.xls" _ ...